# R geom_line - Add labels to grouped data

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, linechart, geom

I have a graph with a bar plot and a line chart together.
I have no problems to show the labels over the bars but I would like to show them also on top the line chart. The line is showing the sum of the qty service for each date variable.
Here is the code:

```
sample <- data.frame(service_type = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),
                     qty = c(38,185,87,29,12,133,2,14,31,2,9,59,60,43,137,135,31,159,15,32,1),
                     year_week = c("2022 - CW02","2022 - CW02","2022 - CW02","2022 - CW03","2022 - CW03","2022 - CW03","2022 - CW04","2022 - CW04","2022 - CW04","2022 - CW05","2022 - CW05","2022 - CW05","2022 - CW06","2022 - CW06","2022 - CW06","2022 - CW07","2022 - CW07","2022 - CW07","2022 - CW08","2022 - CW08","2022 - CW08"),
                     xlabel2 = c("Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22")
)

sample <- sample %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0(year_week, 1), "%Y - CW%U%u")) 


ggplot(sample ) +
  
  aes(x = date, y = qty, fill = service_type) +
  
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  
  geom_line(aes(group = 1), stat = "summary", fun = sum, linetype = "dashed", size = 1, color = '#FF507B') +
  
  geom_text(aes(label=qty), 
            position=position_dodge(7 * 0.9), vjust = 0)+
  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = "#FFC000", B = "#92D050", C = "#AE5AFF"))+
  scale_x_date(
    date_labels = "%Y - CW%U",
    date_breaks = "1 week",
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      breaks = as.Date(paste0("15-", unique(sample$xlabel2)), "%d-%b-%y"),
      labels = \(x) format(x, "%b-%y")
    )
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "left",
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

And the graph is this:

[image]

Thanks to everyone sharing some suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You could add the labels basically the same way as the lines. Use a `geom_text` with `stat="summary"` and to add the computed value as label use `label=after_stat(y)`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sample) +
  aes(x = date, y = qty, fill = service_type) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(
    aes(group = 1),
    stat = "summary", fun = sum,
    linetype = "dashed", size = 1, color = "#FF507B"
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = qty),
    position = position_dodge(7 * 0.9), vjust = 0
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = after_stat(y), group = 1),
    stat = "summary", fun = sum, vjust = 0
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = "#FFC000", B = "#92D050", C = "#AE5AFF")) +
  scale_x_date(
    date_labels = "%Y - CW%U",
    date_breaks = "1 week",
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      breaks = as.Date(paste0("15-", unique(sample$xlabel2)), "%d-%b-%y"),
      labels = \(x) format(x, "%b-%y")
    )
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "left",
    axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5),
    axis.title = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]